# MySQL Selecting Rows with Matching Array Values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been searching around for a bit about how I could select the rows inside my database with an array that matches some values with another array in another table.

I have a table called "users". Inside the table a column named "user_interests" contains an array with interests. An example could be "food, fashion, music" as a value.

In another table called "posts" contains a column named "post_keywords" with the value of another array like inside the "users" table.

Can anyone help me with find the right way of selecting the posts that matches with the users interests? I understand so far that I have to do this in the MySQL query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a case where you should normalize your DB. Multiple values in a column isn't a good structure.

Comment: How would you store an array then? Thanks for response ^^

Comment: Make a user interests table, `userid, Interest`. 1 row per interest. Make a `post_keywords` table (or possible even a keyword table as well if there is a set number of keywords you have), `postid, keyword (or keyword id, if you go with keyword table)`. 1 row per keyword.

Comment: @JensKvist normally, if you have array-like data (so,a collection of things) you'd store the main record in one table (Let's call it `A`), and all the collective data in them in a separate table (Let's call it `B`), then `B` will also store a key that links back to `A`. It's basic many-to-one relationship in SQL.

Comment: @vlaz thanks for the explanation. It's appreciated ;-)

Comment: @chris85 Thanks, I'll try it out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we answer the question that was asked, we should address a more *important* question: whether we should really be storing values in comma separated lists. That's a SQL antipattern.

---

<!-- That particular SQL Antipattern is explained pretty well in Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's excellent tome: **SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming** available from many fine booksellers, including Amazon

[https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

-->

The chapter also addresses a more appropriate SQL Pattern, storing values as separate *rows*, each value on its own row. That's how SQL was designed to operate... on rows.

---

After considering the warnings, if you still have a need to search for values in a comma separated lists of values in a string...

MySQL provides a **`FIND_IN_SET`** function, which will return the *position* of a value within a list.

If a matching value is found, the function will return a positive integer.

If a matching value is *not* found, the function will return 0. If either of the arguments is NULL, the function will return NULL.

As a simple demonstration of how the function works:

```
  SELECT FIND_IN_SET('bowling' ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 0
       , FIND_IN_SET('food'    ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 1
       , FIND_IN_SET('fashion' ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 2
       , FIND_IN_SET('music'   ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 3
```

To make use of that in a query, MySQL allows us to use an expression in a boolean context...

```
  SELECT t.id
    FROM my_table t
   WHERE FIND_IN_SET('food'  ,t.my_comma_separated_list_col)
     AND FIND_IN_SET('music' ,t.my_comma_separated_list_col)
```

This would return rows from `my_table` that had values in `my_comma_separated_list_col` such as:

```
'food,music'
'bowling,dancing,food,music'
'music,food'
```

If the specified search value (e.g. 'food') is found in the list, `FIND_IN_SET` returns a positive integer, which evaluates to TRUE in a boolean context.

If the specified value is not found in the list, `FIND_IN_SET` returns a 0, which evaluates to FALSE.

A return of NULL is just a NULL, neither TRUE nor FALSE.

---

**NOTES:**

A NULL value will cause FIND_IN_SET to return NULL.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(NULL  ,NULL)                        -- > NULL
     , FIND_IN_SET(NULL  ,'food,fashion,music')        -- > NULL 
     , FIND_IN_SET('food',NULL)                        -- > NULL
```

Leading and trailing spaces in the values in the list, or the value being searched for will not be found. Unless both the *search* value and the *list* value are an exact match including leading and trailing spaces. (So, just don't use any spaces between the values in the list):

Leading and/or trailing spaces in the list of values results in "not found"

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('bowling'  ,' food, fashion, music') -- > 0
     , FIND_IN_SET('food'     ,' food, fashion, music') -- > 0 !
     , FIND_IN_SET('fashion'  ,' food, fashion, music') -- > 0 !
     , FIND_IN_SET('music'    ,' food, fashion, music') -- > 0 !
;    
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('bowling'  ,'food ,fashion ,music ') -- > 0
     , FIND_IN_SET('food'     ,'food ,fashion ,music ') -- > 0 !
     , FIND_IN_SET('fashion'  ,'food ,fashion ,music ') -- > 0 !
     , FIND_IN_SET('music'    ,'food ,fashion ,music ') -- > 0 !
;
```

leading or trailing spaces in values cause "not found"

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('bowling'  ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 0
     , FIND_IN_SET('food '    ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 0 !
     , FIND_IN_SET(' fashion' ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 0 !
     , FIND_IN_SET(' music '  ,'food,fashion,music')    -- > 0 !
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have just red a bunch of articles myself explaining why I should operate in rows instead of using data stored array lists. I will try to reach my goal with the FIND_IN_SET function.

Comment: But I have already made a database named "keywords" that contains "post_id" and "keyword_value". Same thing have I done to "interests" which contains "user_id" and "interest_value". Now, how can I select the "posts" which keywords from the "keywords" table matches the interests from the "interests" table that are applied to the user logged in using the "user_id" column in the "interests" table?

Comment: @JensKvist: I already answered the question you asked... regarding "array in a table".  (MySQL doesn't have an "array" datatype. You might have been asking about the SET datatype, or about some way you had serialized an "array" into some binary format... given that you hadn't identified how the "array" was being stored, I "guessed" that you might be storing a comma separated list in a character column. I answered the question about how to determine if a value was in a comma separated list. If you have *different* question, then search SO and if you don't find an answer, ask another question.